# How to wrap d3 axis labels in <a> elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

#### Basic Problem:

I have some scale

```
var y = d3.scalePoint().domain(['a','b','c']).range([0,100]);
```

I can make an axis for that scale

```
var y_axis = svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

How can I make the ticks be links?

#### Complication:

It's pretty straightforward to

```
d3.selectAll('.tick').on('click', (d) => open_link_related_to(d))
```

But since I want to be able to **download an SVG** of the plot and have the links continue to work, the strategy would need to look more like:

```
d3.selectAll('.tick').insert("a").attr("xlink:href", (d) => text_link_related_to(d))
```

However, `insert` doesn't *wrap* the tick in the `<a>` element -- it gets inserted below. Is it possible to wrap the label with `tickformat` or by some other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the cleanest and idiomatic way to do this is using an `each()`. You can always do it using the `tickFormat()`, but it will seem a bit awkward.

Using the `each()` method we can select all `<text>` elements in the axis, then select their parents (which is a `<g>`), append the `<a>` element to the parents and finally moving `this` (which is the text itself) to the `<a>` element:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick text").each(function(d) {
  const a = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://www." + d + ".com");//change this for your function
  a.node().appendChild(this);
});
```

Here is a demo (by the way, Stack snippet won't open the link):

```js
const w = 500,
  h = 100;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("heiht", h);

const scale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(['google', 'stackOverflow', 'amazon'])
  .range([50, w - 50]);

const axis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scale))

d3.selectAll(".tick text").each(function(d) {
  const a = d3.select(this.parentNode).append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://www." + d + ".com")
    .attr("target", "_blank");
  a.node().appendChild(this);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And here a JSFiddle where you can actually open the links: https://jsfiddle.net/xmtdfcks/

If you inspect your tick, you'll find something like this:

```
<g class="tick" opacity="1" transform="translate(250.5,0)">
    <line stroke="#000" y2="6"></line>
    <a href="https://www.stackOverflow.com" target="blank">
        <text fill="#000" y="9" dy="0.71em">stackOverflow</text>
    </a>
</g>
```

Comment: Thanks @gerardofurtado!

Comment: I have another axis question if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51424855/d3-js-how-to-draw-an-arbitrary-number-of-axes

Comment: @AlexLenail You don't have to delete your question. There is nothing wrong in a question because it's a duplicate: a duplicate target is just a previously existing answer.

Comment: Thanks for the kindness, Gerardo! Since the question I thought I was asking turned out to be just a logic bug, I felt the question didn't belong on SO. It's sort of perplexing to me though that JS `=>` doesn't bind scope... coffeescript `->` does..